# How to let a user access code ran server-side

Tags: python, server

This is a bit of a cryptic title so let me explain, I want to let users basically use code from a server (like pythonanywhere or something similar), as if they were running the code themselves. For example, if on the server code, I had a `print('hello world')`, the user could connect to the server, and it show `hello world` for them.

Comment: You mean like what ideone.com does?

Comment: No, more so of a user connects to the server, then the code is executed on the server for that user.

Comment: So you just want to run a Python script and have its output sent to the client? Take a look at CGI.

Comment: Kinda, though the idea is to have the client also be able to send specific commands back to the server.

Comment: What you really need is a web application that acts as a virtual terminal, letting the user interact with the application as if they were logged in. I don't think this is easy with regular HTTP, it could be done using WebSockets.

Comment: Have you ever used a command called `netcat`? It's usually packaged with `nmap` family of tools. With netcat, you can run the following command on one terminal (server): `ncat --sh-exec 'exec python -i 2>&1' -lkp 8080`, and on another terminal (client) you run `ncat localhost 8080`. This will give your client a python shell to run commands in. If you wanted, you can go as far as to use an nginx/apache web server to expose the port to clients. There are some security concerns however, so something I've done in the past is to run the server as a systemd Dynamic User, with limited environment.